# Can't manage to build and run a bottle.py app

Tags: python, bottle, docker-build

I've been trying to setup a container to run an app with the bottle framework. Read everything I could find about it, but even so I can't do it. Here's what I did:

**Dockerfile:**

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:2.7

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8080

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME World

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

**app.py:**

```
import os
from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/<name>')
def index(name):
    return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=name)

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

**requirements.txt**

```
bottle
```

By running the command `docker build -t testapp` I create the container.
Then by running the command `docker run -p 8080:8080 testapp` I get this terminal output:

`Bottle v0.12.13 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://localhost:8080/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.`

But when I go to `localhost:8080/testing` I get `localhost refused connection`.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is this line:

```
run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

It is exposing it for "localhost" insde the container you are running the code. You can use python library `netifaces` to get container external interface if you want to but I suggest you to set `0.0.0.0` as `host` like:

```
run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Then you will be able to access `http://localhost:8080/` (asuming your docker engine is at localhost)

EDIT: mind your previous container might still be listening on 8080/tcp.  Remove or stop previous container first.